# Which file in Magento is the point at which the product description is pulled from the DB and sent to the browser

Tags: localisation, language

I'm currently working on language translations in Magento and it seems the translate.csv within locale/ doesn't contribute towards replacing product name/description. I need to add this functionality in and to do so I need to identify the location, within the code, that the product name/description is pulled from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product attribute values are not translatable via `translate.csv` or inline translate.
They are managed separately. If you need to translate a product attribute on a certain language, edit the product in the backend, select from the top left selector the store view that is needed.
You should see near each attribute that can have different values on different store views (like name and description) a checkbox called 'Use default values'. Uncheck it and you should be able to modify the value. Save and reindex if needed.

And to answer your question, the file that rendered the description is `app/design/fontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml`.
The line that does it is:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description')
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Don't leave loose ends.